# SCNReferenceNode from URL to .scn file does not find textures next to the file

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, scnnode

in my iOS app, I download a .scn file from a webserver, it is thus copied locally.
Next to the downloaded file, I copy the texture files. Relevant or not: these textures are stored locally, not downloaded.

I then create a `SCNReferenceNode` from the local `URL` of the downloaded .scn file.
There is a check (print) in my code for the scn file :

`found SCN file at file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/01F588F9-98AB-4EC8-A948-5165D69074B0/Documents/myTmpDir/model.scn`

and another check for the texture:

`FILE EXISTS at url = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/01F588F9-98AB-4EC8-A948-5165D69074B0/Documents/myTmpDir/Maison%20MSG%2013%20Wapper%20snowdust/Bois234_3.jpg`

But when I load the `SCNReferenceNode`, **I get the following error**:

`[SceneKit] Error: Failed to load : <C3DImage 0x282455a00 src:Maison%20MSG%2013%20Wapper%20snowdust/Bois234_3.jpg [0.000000x0.000000]>
[SceneKit] Error: Cannot load image Maison%20MSG%2013%20Wapper%20snowdust/Bois234_3.jpg. Using dummy texture.`

Note that the .scn file has a relative path to the textures directory. Both are at the right place when I verify by inspecting the container of the app.

If in XCode I put the texture files directory in Assets.xcassets, then the textures are loaded correctly. It looks like the relative path to the textures will not work.
I tried to change the working directory, but still no happy result.

Another fun fact, If I download the app container, and open the .scn file on my mac (with the textures directory being correctly next to it), the textures are applied properly.

I'm out of ideas to solve this problem, any help would be appreciated :-).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'm having a similar issue. i was working on a game, i moved my textures folder inside the scn.assets folder and now no image will load programmatically, even if when i put the folder back to it's original place. and new images won't load either. they all show up in scenekit editor and i can assign them to models.

Answer (score -1):

inside the .mtl file there are references for `Maison%20MSG%2013%20Wapper%20snowdust/Bois234_3.jpg`

remove `Maison%20MSG%2013%20Wapper%20snowdust/` and leave `Bois234_3.jpg` since all the image files will be accessable locally now within the project's `.scnassets` file